# Minimum Privileges Required to Disable a Domain Admin Account

Tags: active-directory, permissions

I'm writing a script that automatically disables new, unauthorized additions to privileged AD groups such as Domain Admins.  The script runs under the  account "groupWatch".

I would like to reduce to minimum the privileges that groupWatch needs in order to disable Domain Admin accounts.  One easy option I have is to get Domain Admins to be [managed by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzBPO.png) groupWatch; when it needs to disable a Domain Admin, it removes it from that group, and then disables it.  I prefer not to give groupWatch the group membership management power because it also means that it can ADD new Domain Admins.

Comment: Have you looked into delegated rights in AD? It's pretty simple to set up. It would restrict changes to disable / enable accounts.. basically any of the checkboxes under the "Account Options" under the user properties.

Comment: @Tim Brigham- thanks, but only Domain Admins can disable other Domain Admins - unless groupWatch is a domain admin (which is what I'm trying to avoid), it wouldn't work